# list one category from list

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list one category from the tables, how can I do this?

```
Table name: products
product_id desc name price qty 

Table name: category
cat_id cat_name
```

I want it to look like this

```
Category 1 (shirts)
Name   Desc Price Qty
```

I have this but I get an error.. Not sure if its the right way to do it

```
SELECT products.*, category.cat_name
FROM prodcuts 
LEFT JOIN category ON products.cat_id = prodcuts.cat_id
WHERE category.cat_name = "shirts"
```

Comment: But you get an error. Care to share that with us? EDIT: Is it `unknown column prodcuts`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your ON statement (you have to have one column from each table to join them) and products is misspelled (prodcuts):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT products.*, category.cat_name
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN category ON products.cat_id = category.cat_id
WHERE category.cat_name = "shirts"
```

EDIT:

One other thing is that you say your products table is:

```
Table name: products
product_id desc name price qty
```

This has no mention of cat_id. You really have to put that in products table (if this wasn't an error on writing the question)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed category table column name in join.

```
SELECT products.*, category.cat_name
FROM prodcuts 
 LEFT JOIN category ON products.cat_id = prodcuts.cat_id
WHERE category.cat_name = "shirts"
```

should be

```
SELECT products.*, category.cat_name
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN category ON products.cat_id = category.cat_id
WHERE category.cat_name = "shirts"
```